# Why can't I overwrite the value of a variable like this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

I'm trying to figure out why I'm having trouble overwriting a value passed to an angularJS directive via an isolate scope (`@`).  I try to overwrite the value of `vm.index` with the following:

`vm.index = parseInt(vm.index, 10)`

However, it doesn't work for some reason.

If I change it to:

`vm.newIndex = parseInt(vm.index, 10)`

It works.  Also, assigning the value on the `$scope` works.

Why doesn't the first method work?

I've created this [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uSsUikNO5VM9N1cwNy2k?p=preview) for reference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Excuse me, I mean't that `vm.index` is not convertted from a string to a number which results in a string concatination when doing something like `{{ vm.index + 1 }}`.

Comment: @brso05, I am aware.  However, scoping is not the issue here as you can verify for yourelf by changing `vm.index = ...` to `vm.newIndex = ...` and updating the template to use `vm.newIndex + 1`.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah could you look at my updated answer..which would give you more idea why `vm.index` won't work by making direct `parseInt` from controller

Comment: @pankajparkar, in my code, I ended up just switching `@` to `=`, but I marked your answer as correct because it does answer the question very well. Thank you.

Comment: The plunker link is dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you used `@` here which need value from an attribute with `{{}}` interpolation directive. And seems like directive is getting loaded first & then the `vm.index` value is getting evaluated. So the changes are not occurring in current digest cycle. If you want those to be reflected you need to run digest cycle in safer way using $timeout.

```
$timeout(function(){
  vm.index = parseInt(vm.index, 10)
})
```

Above thing is ensuring that value is converted to decimal value. The addition will occur on the on the directive html `<h2>Item {{ vm.index + 1 }}</h2>`

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BO2AW2mTzGLGcLiMUFJt?p=preview)

### **The possible reason behind this**

As per @dsfq & my discussion we went through the angular [**`$compile`**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L32) API, & found that their is one method call [**`initializeDirectiveBindings`**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8a1eb1625c080445ce1e519762e1f2d4fd842b72/src/ng/compile.js#L2559) which gets call only when we use `controllerAs` in directive with an isolated scope. In this function there are switch cases for the various binding `@`,`=` and `&` , so as you are using `@` which means one way binding following switch case code gets called.

**Code**

```
case '@':
    if (!optional && !hasOwnProperty.call(attrs, attrName)) {
        destination[scopeName] = attrs[attrName] = void 0;
    }
    attrs.$observe(attrName, function(value) {
        if (isString(value)) {
            destination[scopeName] = value;
        }
    });
    attrs.$$observers[attrName].$$scope = scope;
    if (isString(attrs[attrName])) {
        // If the attribute has been provided then we trigger an interpolation to ensure
        // the value is there for use in the link fn
        destination[scopeName] = $interpolate(attrs[attrName])(scope);
    }
    break;
```

In above code you can clear see that there they placed `attrs.$observe` which is one sort of watcher which is generally used when value is with interpolation like in our case it is the same `{{index}}`, this means that this `$observe` gets evaluated when digest cycle run, That's why you need to put `$timeout` while making `index` value as `decimal`.

The reason @dsfq answer works because he use `=` provides two way binding which code is not putting watcher directly fetching value from the isolated scope, [**here is the code**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8a1eb1625c080445ce1e519762e1f2d4fd842b72/src/ng/compile.js#L2588-L2630). So without digest cycle that value is getting updated.

Comment: This is proper approach for the problem. What happens is that controller gets initialized *before* directive scope configuration is expanded. So controller runs first, then scope => index creates controller's this.index from attribute value which is a string. It overwrites anything what you set in controller.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it has something to do with one-way binding of the scope `index` value. So Angular won't update `scope.index` (or `this.index` in case of `bindToController: true`) because scope is configured as

```
scope: {
    index: '@'
},
```

If you change it to two-way binding like:

```
scope: {
    index: '='
},
```

It will work:

```
<some-directive index="$index"></some-directive>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kq16cpk7gyw8IE7HiaQL?p=preview

**UPD**. @pankajparkar made a good point that updating value in the next digest fixed the issue. This approach for the problem then is closer then what I did in this answer.

Comment: Sorry.but I think you mis-read the question..why the scope thing work and `vm.index`  thing is not working,,I mean to say addition on directive html..

Comment: Yes, looks like your are right, however it's not clear why next digest is needed in this case.

Comment: that is probably because of `@` or rather i can say interpolation directive..directive is getting initalized first & value is populated after evaluation of parser

Comment: Yes, it definitely related to `@` but I'm not sure about entire machinery in this case. But you made a good point with timeout.

Comment: Thanks for you appretiation ..your solution is also cool..but didn''t explained OP's question's answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81334/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-dfsq).

Comment: as per our discussion I updated answer..would you mind to look at it..& feel free to edit it..Thanks :)