# Angular: directive with bindToController 'loses' data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I have `actionButtons` directive:

```
function actionButtons(){
    'use strict';
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'AE',
        bindToController: {
            itemId: '@',
            itemDescription: '@',
            actionsText: '@',
            previewAction: '&',
            previewText: '@',
            editAction: '&',
            editText: '@',
            removeAction: '&',
            removeText: '@'
        },
        controller: ActionButtonsController,
        controllerAs: 'actionButtonsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'src/views/directives/actionButtons.html'
    };
}
```

With `ActionButtonsController` controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function ActionButtonsController() {
    'use strict';
    var viewModel = this;
    //not important assertions
    }
    /**
     *
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    viewModel.hasItemDescription = typeof viewModel.itemDescription === 'string' &&
        viewModel.itemDescription.length > 0;
    /**
     *
     * @type {string}
     */
    viewModel.previewText = viewModel.previewText || 'preview';
    /**
     *
     * @type {string}
     */
    viewModel.editText = viewModel.editText || 'edit';
    /**
     *
     * @type {string}
     */
    viewModel.removeText = viewModel.removeText || 'remove';
    /**
     *
     * @type {string}
     */
    viewModel.actionsText = viewModel.actionsText || 'Actions';

    viewModel.preview = function() {
        viewModel.previewAction();
    };

    viewModel.edit = function() {
        viewModel.editAction();
    };

    viewModel.remove = function() {
        viewModel.removeAction();
    };
}
```

And part of his template, with button:

```
<div class="visible-xs-block btn-group" data-dropdown>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="{{::(actionButtonsCtrl.itemId)}}" type="button"
        data-dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true">
    {{actionButtonsCtrl.actionsText}} <span class="sr-only" data-ng-if="::actionButtonsCtrl.hasItemDescription">
        for {{::(actionButtonsCtrl.itemDescription)}}</span></button>
</div>
```

And that is how I call it in application:

```
<td class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 text-center">
    <div data-action-buttons
         data-item-id="{{author.id + '_' + author.name + '_' + author.surname}}"
         data-item-description="{{author.name + ' ' + author.surname}}"
         data-preview-action="authorCtrl.preview(author)"
         data-edit-action="authorCtrl.edit(author)"
         data-remove-action="authorCtrl.remove(author)"
        ></div>
</td>
```

And the problems is: as you can see from controller code, for example `actionsText` is not required, if is not present it will be set to `Actions`. `itemDescription` also is not required. But if I specify `itemDescription` it is visible in HTML DOM all the time, but `Actions` behaves in very strange way for me: it is set to default value `Actions`, but it is not visible in HTML DOM. The difference between this two is that `actionsText` is bound to `this` in controller's code explicity - but I thought that is default behavior with `bindToController` and this is what I should do when I want to set default value where value is not present. Also, when I debug it (for example by calling one of the function), `actionsText` has `undefined` value, despite the fact that if I debug it when it is created, it has set a default `Actions` value. It doesn't work both with one-time binding (with `::`) and normal situations. Maybe it's something with `scope: {}` from directive's code, but I can't figure it out and I hope for your help - thank you in advance. **P.S.** I tried return `viewModel` variable from controller - it didn't help. **P.S. 2** It works well if `actionsText` is specified (as `data-actions-text={{'Something'}}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bindToController` which indirectly add the scope values to controller `this` context. But this issue is happening because you are using `@` symbol inside your `bindToController` expression.

Whenever there is case with `controllerAs`, `bindToController` & scope with `@` angular handle this thing in sightly different way.

Actually when you use `@` on scope variable inside isolated scope with `controllerAs` & `bindToController` angular put a watch using `$observe` on the expression given on that `attribute` value, [**angular code for same**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8a1eb1625c080445ce1e519762e1f2d4fd842b72/src/ng/compile.js#L2571-L2586)

The solution would use `$timeout` to do all assignment which are going to fetch using `@` of isolated scope value. Because value gets bind in next digest cycle cycle after the `$observe` expression gets evaluated.

**Code**

```
function ActionButtonsController() {
    'use strict';
    var viewModel = this;
    $timeout(function() {
        viewModel.hasItemDescription = typeof viewModel.itemDescription === 'string' &&
            viewModel.itemDescription.length > 0;

        viewModel.previewText = viewModel.previewText || 'preview';

        viewModel.editText = viewModel.editText || 'edit';

        viewModel.removeText = viewModel.removeText || 'remove';

        viewModel.actionsText = viewModel.actionsText || 'Actions';
    })

    viewModel.preview = function() {
        viewModel.previewAction();
    };

    viewModel.edit = function() {
        viewModel.editAction();
    };

    viewModel.remove = function() {
        viewModel.removeAction();
    };
};
```

This is [**detailed version answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013435/2435473)

Comment: @Pneumokok If you want detailed answer you could look at the linked answer.. That would help to clear your concept.. Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar bindToController is useful but what if i still want to do some DOM operations?Must I use link function again?

Comment: @Levis yes..you should..because you will get the angular compiled directive element there..which would be safer thing to manipulate DOM over there.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar So,if I have used controllerAs:"ctrl",may I fetch the controller by using require:'ctrl' and inject it as the fourth argument in link function?..Cuz I want to prevent using the scope option in a directive