# directive not receiving object as a param

Tags: angularjs

I'm coding with AngularJS version 1.5.7.

For some reason, the directive doesn't receive the variable `cdata` which is an `object`.

Why doesn't the directive receive the variable?

Here below I pasted all my code:

**home.js**

```
'use strict';

var home = angular.module('app.home', [
  'global.factory',
  'home.factory',
  'ui.scroll',
  'ui.scroll.jqlite',
  'd.card'
]);

home.controller('HomeController', [
  'homeFactory',
  '$timeout',
  function (homeFactory, $timeout) {

    var data = this;

    data.posterSize = (screen.width - 42) / 3;

    homeFactory.getJSON().then(function (response) {
      data.feed = response.home;
    });

    data.datasource = {
      get: function(index, count, success) {
        $timeout(function() {
          var start = Math.max(0, index);
          var end = Math.min(index + count, data.feed.length);

          var results = [];
          for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            results.push(data.feed[i]);
          }

          success(results);
        }, 100);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

**_home.html**

```
<article ng-controller="HomeController as myHome" class="base-gen" ui-scroll-viewport style="height:100%">
  <card class="card" ui-scroll="element in myHome.datasource" cdata="{{element}}" psize="{{myHome.posterSize}}"></card>
</article>
```

**card.js**

```
'use strict';

var dCard = angular.module('d.card', ['global.factory']);

dCard.directive('card', [ 'globalImages', function (globalImages) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      cdata: '@',
      psize: '@'
    },
    controller: function() {
      console.log(this.cdata);
    },
    controllerAs: 'myCard',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/Modules/card.html'
  };
}]);
```

---

I also want to point out that I've migrated from `angular 1.4.8` to `1.5.7` and from `ui-router 0.2.15` to `0.3.1`

Comment: may be related to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013435/2435473)

Comment: sounds like the problem was related to the ui-scroll module. After fetching it with bower, no more issues. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

The binding in the directive says "=", that means angular will do the binding for you. No need for `{{ }}`.

```
 <article ng-controller="HomeController as myHome" class="base-gen" ui-scroll-  viewport style="height:100%">
   <card class="card" ui-scroll="element in myHome.datasource" cdata="element" psize="{{myHome.posterSize}}"></card>
 </article>
```

With `psize` I am not sure if you need `{{ }}` but for the cdata there is no need for the brackets

Comment: I have updated the post. It was a mistake of my code when copying. The point here is to receive in my directory a `Read Only` data.

Comment: well what you could do instead of `@` is a one way databinding.. `::=`. Makes the markup cleaner and I was thought it looks weird to have markup with `{{ }}`in an attribute of angular when you could overwrite that behaviour